# iOS Simulator not replicating code

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I have come across a strange issue with my simulator (on my iMac). It does not seem to replicate the code I have in Xcode. Even though if I run the same code on my Mac Book Air it works fine.  I have downloaded it to my iPhone and that works fine.  Not sure what I've done. I am running the app on Xcode 6.4 . Is it worth just deleting Xcode and then re-downloading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the iOS Simulator and go to Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...

This wipes the simulated iOS device and should clear up any issues.

If this does not work, try "Product -> Clean" or "Window -> Projects" - select your project from the left hand side and select delete on the right hand side (alongside Derived Data).

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  I think I might have done something to it and will have to rebuild it from scratch.  Although, as I said it works fine on my other computer.

Comment: I have just noticed that I have Main.Storyboard and LaunchScreen.xib are in red on the Copy Bundle Resource. I have tried deleting them before. Should I not have done this?

Comment: You should've left them as is. I suggest completely replacing this version from your iMac with the version that is stored on your Macbook Air or elsewhere. If it is still giving you issues then i'd reinstall Xcode. Is Xcode displaying any errors with the current project?

Comment: I have tried that and now I am getting this error in Xcode

Comment: Here is the error Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 11

Comment: Going to need more of that error log; could you copy the last 10-15ish lines to your original post please?

Comment: Here you are: Program arguments: ormy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stormy.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/briankaty1/Desktop/Developer/TableViewApp/StormyS5V3/build/Stormy.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stormy.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Stormy-Swift.h -Xcc -working-directory/Users/briankaty1/Desktop/Developer/TableViewApp/StormyS5V3 
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 11

Comment: Clean the project, delete derived data again and then recompile. Hopefully that'll do the trick

Comment: Brilliant it works now! Thank you air6199 - Very much appreciated.